# How to exclude all countries that have flag with primary colour in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a set of facts on prolog as follows:

```
primary(red).
primary(blue).
primary(yellow).  

flag(france,red).    
flag(france,blue).    
flag(france,white).     

flag(china,red).    
flag(china,white).    

flag(india,orange).    
flag(india,green).    
flag(india,white).
```

i want to run a query to return a list of countries whose **flag does not contain primary colour** at all. In the case of my program **it should return india** only.

i tried the following code, but it did not work:

```
?- flag(X,Y),not(primary(Y)).   

X = france,    
Y = white ;    
X = china,    
Y = white ;    
X = india,    
Y = orange ;    
X = india,    
Y = green ;    
X = india,    
Y = white.
```

The problem in the result is that the flag of france contains primary colour. But it is returning france because it also has a non primary colour in its flag. so is the case for china.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way Prolog answers to a query doesn't allow you to do this. Whatever the query is, Prolog will go through the list of predicate one by one. With your predicates, Prolog has no way to know if `flag(china,white)` (for example) is the last one attributing a color to the chinese flag, thus you cannot select the flags that **don't** have a specific color.

A way to go around this problem is to use list to store the colors of a flag :

```
flag(france,[red,blue,white]).    

flag(china,[red,white]).  

flag(india,[orange,green,white]).
```

This way, Prolog just go through the list to know if there is a primary color or not.

Here is an example of function that does what you want :

```
no_primary_color(X,[]).
no_primary_color(X,[C|Cs]) :- not(primary(C)),no_primary_color(X,Cs).
```

And the query :

```
?- flag(X,Y), no_primary_color(X,Y).
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you posted asks something like "what countries have colors in their flag that are not primary colors?". As you noticed, this is not exactly what you want.

If you want to use negation, you must first express *exactly* the predicate that you then want to negate. You ask for "countries whose flag *does not* contain primary colour". So let's first express the notion of "countries whose flag *does* contain a primary color"!

```
country_primarycolor(Country, Color) :-
    flag(Country, Color),
    primary(Color).
```

Let's see if this does what we want:

```
?- country_primarycolor(Country, Color).
Country = france,
Color = red ;
Country = france,
Color = blue ;
Country = china,
Color = red ;
false.
```

For the next step we also need to be able to express the notion of "country". This is easy:

```
country(france).
country(china).
country(india).
```

And now, countries whose flag does not contain primary colors:

```
?- country(Country), not(country_primarycolor(Country, _Color)).
Country = india.
```